# How can I delay a systemd service startup until network and ntp time synchronization is accomplished?

Tags: networking, systemd, timestamps

I have an issue on my Linux home server, which doesn't export its NFS shares properly, possibly because the NFS services are started too early, when the network services are not fully synced.
A similar issue exists on my Raspberry Pi, where I have enabled the hardware watchdog and configured it to monitor a file which gets updated at boot and thereafter every 10 minutes.
Alas, when I boot the pi after a longer shutdown (no RTC!), the watchdog gets started way before the time is updated from the network.
Thus, the watchdog triggers a reboot because it sees a too large time difference for the monitored file.
In both cases, I think it is necessary to delay the start of the respective services until the network is fully up and synced.
I have read the hints at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43001223/how-to-ensure-that-there-is-a-delay-before-a-service-is-started-in-systemd, but because both services are standard systemd services I don't know how I should delay them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found this https://blog.debiania.in.ua/posts/2020-11-27-howto-delay-a-systemd-service-until-the-clock-is-synchronized.html, which solved my problems.
The issue already came up 2020 and it still seems not properly solved.
I followed the steps below and now nfs exports work and the watchdog is only started after the system time has been updated.

1. dpkg -l | grep -q "ii *chrony" && apt remove chrony
2. systemctl enable --now systemd-timesyncd.service
3. systemctl enable --now systemd-time-wait-sync.service
4. systemctl edit watchdog.service  # *adding the following lines*
   [Unit]
   After=time-sync.target
   Wants=time-sync.target
5. systemctl edit nfs-server.service # *adding the same lines as in 4.*

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue on a pi.  I modified the ntp start script to run ntpdate first so the clock starts with a good time.  (Yours may already do this.)  ntpdate will get the time correct to within a second at least before it finishes.

Then you can tell your other scripts to depend on ntp and network-online.

Something like

```
[Unit]
After=network-online.target ntp.service
```

Comment: How do you modify a startup script that comes with systemd? Do you just modify it in place, or do you copy it to /etc/systemd/system and modify it there? For the nfs exports there seems to be a bunch of startup scripts and I don't know which systemd script exactly needs to be modified to achieve my goal.

Comment: you can use `systemctl edit`  or you can drop a complete file in `/etc/systemd/system/`.  You could also try modifying the ntp service to put `Before=` lines and list all the nfs services.  (But that might already be the default.)